# EasyMock - request.getSession is null

Tags: java, junit, easymock

I am testing the following method:

```
public static String createSn(HttpServletRequest request, String usrnm) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("UserID", usrnm);

    return session.getId();
}
```

With my `JUnit` test code:

```
HttpServletRequest request = createNiceMock(HttpServletRequest.class);
HttpSession session = createNiceMock(HttpSession.class);
expect(request.getSession()).andReturn(session);

replay(request);
replay(session);

String username="testuser";
String snID = LogInUtils.createSn(request, username);
```

However, these Lines seem to produce a `Null Pointer Exception`:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("UserID", usrnm);
```

In conclusion `request.getSession(true)` dosen't seem to work for my Mock Request. Where did I went wrong?

Thank you for your input :)

Answer (score 4):

You should use:

```
expect(request.getSession(true)).andReturn(session);
```

In your example you mock the method `request.getSession()` which is not called in your code.